# Post to server as soon as user types

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, post

Edited question:

After reading and tinkering for a while, I have now run into a more specific problem:
In my HTML, I have an input field and `oninput`, I have a javascript function setting up and XMLHTTPrequest. I have my input field wrappend into  tags so that in flask, I can access

```
@app.route('/user_input', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def handle_input():
    message = request.form['input']
    return "success"
```

Everything works find, except for sending the user input continuously. I.e., in my js code, I try to get the text input in the text field by

```
var text = document.getElementById("myForm").value
var postVars = 'input='+ text
req.send(postVars)
```

and send it. However, when accessing it in flask, the string is `undefined`. I suppose this is, because I never actually submit the form or anything.

**Behavior I want**

User inputs in text field, as soon as he changes the input send current input to web server.

How to achieve this with the architecture, I am using? Is  just not the way to go?

Comment: Create a form and there create an input field where you can call a javascript function on input that function will make an ajax call with data inside the input field so you're good to go now.

Comment: generally you would like to access the value of the *input*, not of the form.

Comment: that solved it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using NodeJS, you could implement sockets features and stream data from your client to server on keypress event. Since I am not sure what server side language you are using, this maybe completely irrelevant to you, but NodeJS implementation of your requirement is simple enough.

Comment: I wanted to use Python flask to run my server. Can you do on keypress events with python, too? In principle, I am open to using anything. :)

Comment: In that case, AJAX should be the way to go. Create a POST request on your server side and send the post request on your keypress event.
Your code could look something like :

<input type="text" onkeypress="sendPost()">

function sendPost(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       //do what you will with the response
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "<post_request_url>", true);
  xhttp.send();
}